# note: This error originates from a subprocess and is likely not a problem with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, video-streaming

while downloading `pip install vidstream`
I am using Python 3.10.1, win 10 pro and the lastest version of VS c++

I faced this problem :

````
src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: б¬. ЇаҐ¤л¤гйҐҐ ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­ЁҐ "MS_WIN64"
src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: portaudio.h: No such file or directory,
error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.31.31103\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

Encountered error while trying to install package.

pyaudio

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure. ```


what should I do?
````

Comment: My guess is a missing dependency that must be installed (outside from Python). But only with the full error message we'll be able to tell for sure.

Comment: I have added more information about the error, but there are unreadable characters there, I hope this will not greatly affect the understanding of the problem